# Adding class active to current slide 3d carrousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this js for a 3d carousel. And I am straggling when assigning an active class to the current slide. Below is my latest try. I think I was closest with another approach. I didnt include the css because I didnt find it relevant, if need it please let me know.
https://jsfiddle.net/ubxvyh5j/6/

```
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
currdeg = 0;

$(".next").on("click", {d: "n"}, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", {d: "p"}, rotate);

function rotate(e) {
    if (e.data.d == "n") {
        currdeg = currdeg - 120;      
    }
    if (e.data.d == "p") {
        currdeg = currdeg + 120;
    }
carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)"
  });
  $(this('.item')).addClass('active'); // this is what is not working
}
```

Html

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
```

css

```
.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}
.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: I cant understand how it should work please add the css it will be much easier

Comment: @Cuzi, css added

Comment: I've created [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubxvyh5j/4/) for you. which of the items should get the `.active` class and in which scenario?

Comment: In this case the A, I added the prev next css to the op

Comment: I still cant understand what is the logic that you try to apply here so I cant understand which of the elements should get the active class?

Comment: Please notice that I made a mistake in my original css,  transform: rotateY should increase in 120 degres, 0, 120, 240...

Comment: I made some css changes in the jsfinddle, its normal you couldnt understand anything, my code was incorrect. sorry :( it should be fine now https://jsfiddle.net/ubxvyh5j/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a counter that remembers the location of the current active element.
You cannot use `$(this('.item')).addClass('active');` since it's just not a valid statement.

I fixed your JavaScript code so it will work:

```
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    currdeg = 0,
    itemsArray = carousel.find('.item'),
    currActive = 0;

$(".next").on("click", {d: "n"}, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", {d: "p"}, rotate);

function rotate(e) {
    var $active = $(carousel.find('.active'));

    $active.removeClass('active');
    if (e.data.d == "n") {
        currdeg = currdeg - 120;  
        currActive = (currActive + 1) % itemsArray.length;
    }
    if (e.data.d == "p") {
        currdeg = currdeg + 120;
        currActive = (currActive - 1 + itemsArray.length) % itemsArray.length;

    }
    $(itemsArray[currActive]).addClass('active'); // add the class to the active element
    carousel.css({
      "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
      "-moz-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
      "-o-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
      "transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)"
    }); 
}
```

You can see an [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ubxvyh5j/13/)

Comment: That's what I was originally going to is use `%` modulus! I was so tired I didn't want to deal with any math so I made a switch. This is what I'd do if I had enough sleep =_= zzzzZZZZ +1

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Had the limits before increment, it was skipping count. Corrected it by placing limits after increment. Added a style to `.active` to track it's current assignment. If the current `.item` has a dashed red outline, then it's functioning correctly. The style of course is just for testing so it;'s safe to remove.

---

The `.carousel` is rotating and the `.items` are along for the ride. So try to reference an `.item` by a counter. Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
  currdeg = 0;
// .item.a is at starting position 1
var counter = 0;
$(".next").on("click", {
  d: "n"
}, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", {
  d: "p"
}, rotate);

function rotate(e) {

  console.log(e.data.d);
  if (e.data.d == "n") {
    currdeg = currdeg - 120;
    // Incremental increase forward direction
    counter++;
  }
  if (e.data.d == "p") {
    currdeg = currdeg + 120;
    // Incremental decrease backward direction
    counter--;
  }
  // If you go past A you end up at C
  if (counter < 1) {
    counter = 3
  }
  // If you go past C you end up at A
  if (counter > 3) {
    counter = 1
  }
  console.log(counter);
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY(" + currdeg + "deg)"
  });
  // Remove '.active' class on any .item that has it
  $('.item').removeClass('active');

  // Pass counter to a switch function
  switch (counter) {
    // If counter = 1
    case 1:
      // addClass .active to .a
      $('.a').addClass('active');
      // Stop and leave switch, etc....
      break;
    case 2:
      $('.b').addClass('active');
      break;
    case 3:
      $('.c').addClass('active');
      break;
    default:
      $('.a').addClass('active');
      break;
  }

}
```

```css
.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #ed1c24;
}

.b {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #0072bc;
}

.c {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px);
  background: #39b54a;
}

.next,
.prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #999;
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s, top 0.1s;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.active {
  outline: 5px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item a active">A</div>
    <div class="item b">B</div>
    <div class="item c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="next">Next</div>
<div class="prev">Prev</div>
```